# Fe 2+ and MnO4- titration?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, redox, titration

As a lab experiment, I am preparing a mixture of iron tablets dissolved in sulfuric acid so they can be titrated against $\ce{MnO4-}$. The tablet contain insoluble filler material.

Why is it important this 'filler' be removed when preparing the iron tablets solution?

Answer (score 1):

Insoluble doesn't mean unreactive. The filler must be something which would be oxidized by permanganate in acidic solution.

Comment: Please explain this further, I don't fully understand. Thanks

Comment: How? You don't say what the tablets are. There is no information on what the filler is. You didn't provide any details on how the separation was done. // The one thing I do know is that permanganate in acid solution is a very strong oxidizer. For instance cellulose wouldn't dissolve in water, but an acidic permanganate solution would react with it.

Comment: Thanks. The tablets were mainly made from Iron ii Salt, and the filler was calcium sulfate (and other substances). ?